# When do I meet the Persona team that I did not choose?

Tags: persona-q

In Persona Q you choose either the Persona 3 Protagonist or the Persona 4 Protagonist to follow throughout the game. The game starts with only their team. Eventually both teams meet up anyway. At what point in the story do the teams meet up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will meet the other team when you reach the final boss of the first Labyrinth. You will have to fight some soldiers and after a few reinforcements arrive the other team will show up and you will continue the fight with the mixed teams. After that you can use any of the characters from either team immediately. They will also all join you at the average level of your main team.